# how to covert regular expression in simplest form?

Tags: regular-expressions

[image]

I have made this expression from nfa (NFA to regular expression) :
   (a+ab+aa*b)*(a+a*a) but at book answers it is written like this : (a+aa*b)*(a*a)

I am thinking that the my answer is same as book but they have converted it into it just like quadratic equation as we do. SO any one who can help me or book answer is wrong or mine is wrong BUT IF BOTH ARE SAME THEN TELL ME HOW TO CONVERT INTO BOOK FORM?

Comment: ???. i am waiting as i am preparing for my exam.

Comment: You can see in your addition that some terms are included in others. Since addition is union, if $L_1 \subset L_2$ then $L_1+L_2=L_2$. Here, remember that $a^*$ means $a,aa,aaa,\ldots$ but ALSO the empty word $\epsilon$. So $a\epsilon b = ab \in aa^*b$, you can simplify $ab + aa^*b=aa^*b$. The same holds for the second part, $\epsilon a = a \in a^*a$ so $a +a^*a=a^*a$